# Compare Position Array with button location

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an `ArrayList` of points which every point have value X,Y for mouse Coordinate, I have a button I want to compare the button location with the Array locations to check if the button locate in this locations or not. when try this code can't  make any thing because the location of the button have different value of points in the `ArrayList`, How to check if this button locate in the points range ?

this is my code

```
 for (int i = 0; i < _points.Count; i++)
     {
     if (_points.Contains(button1.Location))
       {
                    button1.PerformClick();
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try this code is work for me correctly, Thanks for Help

```
PointR s = new PointR();
  s.X=button1.Location.X;
  s.Y=button1.Location.Y;
foreach (PointR w in _points)
     {
     if (s.X >= w.X && s.Y >=w.Y)
      {
            button1.PerformClick();
             break;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(button1.Location, button1.Size);
    for (int i = 0; i < _points.Count; i++)
    {
        if (rect.Contains(_points[i]))
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```

But as you say that these points refer to mouse positions, you will need to subtract the form location from it. I'll leave this part for you.